# How do airliners cross the ocean without GPS?

Tags: navigation, gnss, oceanic, navaids

How do airliners cross the ocean without GPS?

Do they use dead-reckoning or are there navigation aids floating out there?

Comment: It's worth noting that ICBMs cross the oceans on combination of INS (as mentioned in some answers) and automated star tracking devices data (as it will be unwise to rely on any sort of ground/satellite assisted navigation during the global nuclear meltdown). Same applies to many military planes, such as a venerable SR71 (which was equipped with a daylight capable star tracker).

Comment: @oakad The U-2 also used celestial navigation, especially when flying  close to the north pole, which they often did to see what the USSR was doing at it's far-northern nuclear test sites. During the early stages of the Cuban Missile Crisis, one of these flights accidentally crossed the Russian far-east after the pilot miscalculated his return to Alaska.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Well, most airlines *do* cross the ocean with GPS in today's world.

That being said, most (if not all) transcontinental airliners, and many flying domestic routes as well, have what's called an [inertial navigation system](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/2275/what-is-an-inertial-navigation-system-how-does-it-work) (a form of dead-reckoning where gyros and accelerometers are used to compute changes in position and attitude). The INS feeds into the flight management computer which is used to cross-check the GPS position, and can be used as a primary navigation source should the GPS signal be lost or corrupted.

Prior to GPS, inertial navigation was the primary means of navigating across oceans. However, a great many airplanes did cross oceans before INS... with varying success. The general idea was to use a combination of dead-reckoning, radio beacons where you can find them (small islands and coastlines), the sun (with the help of a [sextant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sextant)) during the day, and the stars at night. Hopefully, this puts you in position after some period of time to pickup ground-based navigational aids, or to identify a coastline. This actually works pretty well if your wind estimates are good, and the margin for error is high enough. As DeltaLima points out, long-range radio navigation systems also started to emerge around World War II (LORAN and Decca) which had a much greater range than previous radio beacons, and therefore decreased the amount of time required to fly by dead-reckoning alone. By the time inertial navigation became prevalent in the 1970's, airlines were already providing reliable transcontinental passenger flights every day.

Another possible outcome is that your plane is lost in the ocean, never found, and the Discovery Channel funds an expedition to look for you 75 years later.

Comment: Many aircraft, the Vulcan included (first hand experience) have a sextant protruding from the fuselage.  The navigator would take star fixes - just as the Vikings did when they crossed the Atlantic.

Comment: Do i read correctly that planes don't have compasses?

Comment: @atk No, a compass is required equipment on all certified airplanes.

Comment: @atk Note that the usefulness of copmasses decreases as you get close to the poles, which some intercontinental flights do.

Comment: @Simon: The upper windows on earlier 737s and other airliners of that era served the same purpose.

Comment: @atk.  How would a compass help with an oceanic crossing since you want to fly a great circle route?

Comment: @Simon it would help you maintain a particular heading for a given amount of time.

Comment: An aeronautical engineer with Airbus once boasted to me that the IMU on new Airbuses would localize the aircraft to within 3 feet after a cross-country flight, without any GPS input other than the starting location.

Comment: @Chris "Cross country" and "airbus" might mean the width of France - about 1,000km and 3 hours, the width of the UK (smaller) or the width of the US or USSR.  Any would indicate good accuracy for an INS, but the statement is rather ambiguous.

Comment: @AdamDavis yeah, I wish I could have gotten more specific info from him. It was at a US facility so I'm going to guess he meant across the US, but I can't say for sure, sorry!

Comment: @atk: a compass is an inefficient guide to crossing an ocean. If you take off from the Eastern USA and fly a constant 'due east' you do get to Europe eventually, via a Great Circle route. But this is a much longer route than the path usually taken which goes much closer to the pole. I suppose you could do that on a compass by changing the heading by N degrees every M minutes. A compass also doesn't take drift into account, so you could be dozens or hundreds of km off after your crossing.

Answer (score 23):

We were crossing the seas centuries before GPS, INS or really any other form of modern technology.

All you need is a clock, a compass and a sextant. And some largely-forgotten skills, like how to do math without a smartphone.

Comment: Surely you can use a smartphone if you put it in flight mode.

Comment: Did the Vikings not have Calculator apps on their smartphones, or something? :p

Comment: We were crossing the seas centuries before clock (that would of use on a rolling ship) too—first chronometer sufficiently accurate to be of use for navigation was only created in 1761.

Comment: And I don't think Vikings already knew about compass either. Neither did Polynesians.

Comment: US Navy ships train on sextant navigation and practice it every day

Answer (score 18):

In the days before GPS, we routinely crossed the oceans using inertial navigation systems.

The system I was familiar with used 3 separate inertial systems (Carousel was the brand name). You could choose to navigate by any single one, but the most common way of using them was to have the autopilot "average" the positions. You could also choose to exclude any given INS, in which case if you were averaging, you were averaging only two.

For the North Atlantic MNPS airspace system, You manually updated each INS passing over your last known ground position fix. When you passed over your first ground-based nav fix on the other side, you again manually updated the INSes with that information and then recorded in the maintenance log how far off left or right each INS was in the maintenance log. There were standards. Offhand I'm not sure I am remembering them correctly, but what I seem to recall was a max error of 2 nautical miles per hour flown without update. The MNPS had at the time a max error allowed without penalty of 10 nautical miles left or right of course. If that was exceeded, points were deducted from your company's score. Lose enough points and the company would not be allowed in fly in MNPS.

Off course errors of two to six nautical miles for a crossing were typical.

There is the story, true or not I do not know, of the captain who, when hand held GPSs first became available, used one to cross the North Atlantic, and had a near zero off course error. When ATC complimented him on that, he blurted out that he had used his hand-held. He was subsequently violated for using a non-approved navigational system. Whether the incident really happened, I don't know, but an airline's FAA approved op specs specifies not only which navigation methods are to be used but also which systems by brand and model name (at least back when I was flying).

Comment: At least until the early 2000s hand held GPS sold in the US would lock out at 99/199knots to prevent you using them in aircraft. The makers were scared they would be sued. To use them for an airborne science experiment we had to buy special FAA grade GPS

Answer (score 9):

Most aircraft cross the atlantic by GPS, usually with INS as backup. INS as the primary form of navigation is still used as well.

Historically, a combination of dead reckoning and long range radio navigation systems were used on transatlantic routes. These include [Decca](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decca_Navigator_System), [LORAN C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LORAN) and [Omega](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OMEGA_Navigation_System).

Omega was shut down in 1997, Decca in 2000 and LORAN C ceased in 2010.

Comment: LORAN C/eLORAN is still in operation in some parts of the world...

Answer (score 1):

They do use GPS, with backups, as the other answers describe.

If your question is inspired by MH370, remember that GPS tells you where you are: it doesn't tell anyone else where you are. GPS works by having a bunch of satellites sending out signals and, based on the signals you hear, you can calculate your own position. A GPS user doesn't transmit anything back to the satellites. What MH370 lacked was a system that was reporting its location back to base.

Comment: Thanks, I did know that about GPS, this wasn't inspired by MH370. I was just wondering how it would be done in aircraft without GPS ;)

Answer (score 1):

Mode of air navigation I've witnessed:

- Celestial - sextant and charts. Like, no kidding, right out of days of sailing ships.
- Atmospheric pressure - driving along specific barometric pressure lines. By no means a primary form of navigation.
- Omega - now obsolete. Triangulates on a small number of very powerful radio transmitters spread around the globe. At least good enough to hit the ADIZ w/in limits. I'm told when particularly close to a transmitter it can be as accurate as A Cat 2 ILS beam.
- Inertial Nav -
- GPS. what's that?

Comment: Omega were effectively high power NBDs. Pretty accurate if you knew how to use them properly. Of course pilots could also tune their NBDs to commercial stations with known locations (as the ill fated B-17 group did that flew into Hawaii on 7 December 1941) and get the same effect.

Comment: Are you referring to Non-Birectional Deacons?

Comment: Speaking of commercial stations... At about 100 miles east of Hawaii we could tune our NDB to KRLD, Dallas Texas. Why we could routinely pick up this particular station 3,600 miles away is a mystery to me. Maybe it was some dealership option package for these Texas Air National Guard airplanes.