# Is it true that there are VOR/DME and/or TACAN stations in the oceans?

Tags: navigation, navaids, oceanic, transatlantic

Are there any VORs placed in the oceans for navigation. Is it true that VORs or TACANs are placed on ships to help oceanic flights, for example flights across the Atlantic?

Comment: Hello samba siva, welcome to aviation.stackexchange!

Comment: Related: [How do airliners cross the ocean without GPS?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/2589/753)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are no ship-based VOR's or TACAN's specifically dedicated to transatlantic flights. Transatlantic flights navigate using the inertial navigation system and GPS.

TACAN's are used on board naval ships for military aircraft to find their way to the ships, but this is typically not for flights across the ocean.

Comment: There has been a FAA study for North Atlantic [Long Distance Navigation](https://books.google.com/books?id=nbb2Gd6KMvgC&pg=PA287) (LODISNAV, part of "Accordion" research) in the early 60s with VORTAC oceanic stations. Didn't make its way to actual use. Aircraft carriers were used as testbeds.