# How accurate is an Inertial Navigation System

Tags: navigation

I was surprised to learn that an [inertial navigation system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inertial_navigation_system) even works at all; I'd expect that the integration drift would throw the *velocity* measurement off badly enough, not to mention the position. [Other questions](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/2275/what-is-an-inertial-navigation-system-how-does-it-work) have asked about how these systems work, and the answers have explained that cross-checks with other measurements which give absolute position (e.g. GPS) improve accuracy.

But given a state-of-the art INS which operates in isolation (no interfacing with airspeed, GPS, etc) from takeoff, how much drift could we expect for, say, a normal transatlantic flight? Does this change if the aircraft flies through turbulence?