# What's required for the ADS-B to function? A GPS or Mode S Transponder?

Tags: ads-b, transponder, mode-s

Jeppesen defines the ADS-B as a surveillance system broadcasting **GPS-derived** positions and other information such as velocity over the data link. Yet, [the Wiki article on ADS-B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aviation_transponder_interrogation_modes#Issues_with_Mode_S_transponders) relates it to the **Mode S** transponder system. So the ADS-B operates either on a GPS or on Mode S. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Your ADS-B transmitter gets its position data from a GPS source. Then it transmits the data using either 1090ES or 978 Universal Access. Mode S transponders already transmit detailed information about the aircraft, called a 'squit'. Some can be upgraded to send 'Extended Squitter' info. The other alternative, in the US only, is to transmit the info on the 978 band. More info at http://www.garmin.com/us/intheair/ads-b/squit/

Comment: @mins What I meant is closer to "What's required for the ADS-B to function? A GPS or Mode S Transponder?" I'll change the title

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[ADS-B, Automatic Dependent Surveillance - Broadcast](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/213/19), is a  broadcast of the aircraft's position and other information.

The position is determined by a GPS receiver. It is possible to use another qualified position source, but today it is [de facto GPS](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/15814/19). Other GNSS (Galileo, GLONASS, Bei-Dou) are other likely candidates in the future, but as far as I know, none have been certified for ADS-B yet.

The broadcast is usually by the Mode S transponder but can also be done by a dedicated transmitter / transceiver in the Mode S format and frequency (1090 MHz).

In the USA below 18 000 ft, in addition to the Mode S based ADS-B, a system based on Universal Access Transceiver  (UAT)  is used. This operates on 978 MHz

A third broadcast system was VDL mode 4, it was never rolled out on large scale.

So ADS-B uses GPS to determine the position and it operates either  on 1090 MHz (a frequency also used by Mode S)  or 978 MHz to broadcast information.

Comment: Then in order for the ADS-B to function, an aircraft should be equipped with both a GPS and a mode S transponder (or UAT). Without either of them, the ADS-B simply doesn't function. Correct?

Comment: You could have an ADS-B transmitter on 1090MHz that is not a Mode S transponder, but that is unusual.

Comment: Okay I'll take it as yes. Thank you for your detailed explanation.

Comment: Nothing requires the position to be determined by GPS specifically. Requirements are just for precision and any [GNSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satellite_navigation) can do that, so GPS, [GLONASS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GLONASS), [Gallileo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galileo_(satellite_navigation)) (and [BeiDou-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compass_navigation_system) is under construction and some more are planned). Since the principle and protocols are similar, modern receivers may use more than one.

Comment: @JanHudec you are right of course, but effectively only GPS is used at the moment.

Comment: @DeltaLima, also, even if there are already dual-system chips in use (they are in use in handheld devices for quite some time, but certification for aviation takes time), I doubt any chip would only use some other system and pass on GPS.

Comment: The other thing is, however, that it's still quite common to see aircraft report just INS position, which shows on FR24 as aircraft landing say a mile off the runway.

Comment: I believe that the position can be from any approved position source, which just happens to be GPS. In theory one could derived the position from a non-GPS source such as Galileo, GLONASS or INS/IRS if it meet the position source requirements. See https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?node=14:2.0.1.3.10#se14.2.91_1227

Comment: FYI, some older plane's have a waiver to transmit a position derived from non-GPS (usually DME/DME/IRU) sources, because there is no certified GPS available for those types.