# Aside from primary radar, how did ATC monitor planes' locations before ADS-B?

Tags: radar, ads-b

From what I understand, air traffic controllers can monitor planes with radar, often called primary radar, or with ADS-B. I've seen ADS-B called "secondary radar," although it isn't really radar, but I've also seen the phrase "secondary radar" used referring to something that ADS-B replaced. I've also seen references to "SSR" (secondary surveillance radar? just a guess), which also appears to have been replaced by ADS-B.

My understanding:

1. Primary radar: "normal" radar, similar to what ships have; has been used for a long time and is still used
2. Secondary radar: originally "SSR"(?); SSR replaced by ADS-B

Is this correct?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secondary_surveillance_radar

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between SSR and ADS-B?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/87311/what-is-the-difference-between-ssr-and-ads-b) and see also [How is radar separation assured between primary and secondary targets?](/q/62215/)

Comment: See also too [How prevalent is traditional radar tracking of commercial aircraft?](/q/11440/) ...it seems like any one of the "related" posts that should have appeared when you typed this question would have answered it.