# Why is this 777 zig zagging over the Pacific (and delayed by 2.5 hours in air)?

Tags: safety, commercial-aviation

Why is this 777 (CX 806 on June 6 2017) zig zagging over the Pacific (and delayed by 2.5 hours in air)?

[image]

Comment: it's a bug in flightstats' visualization. Flightradar shows no such behaviour and says the flight will land approx. 30 min. in advance.

Comment: My work site does not allow me to see images here, but looking up that flight in flight aware for June 6 does not show any deviations (and it landed 18 minutes early)...

Comment: Sorry my post was wrong -- June 16.

Comment: It's not exactly the same question, but the reason is the same, and therefore I suggest to close as duplicate: [Why do aircraft on Flight Radar 24 jump around randomly sometimes?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/2269/) Another possibility: [Why did the Flightaware groundspeed readout suddenly spike for this flight?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/16610/)

Comment: @mins, you mean it isn't just the pilots having fun? _disappointed..._ :)

Comment: @FreeMan: Well.... they are having fun in reality, and they also need these tracks to spread their chemicals all over. But you also know... there is this little secret inter-government communication plan to convince people it's a bug in visualization software, using SE. Don't you receive your bonus when explaining the "bug"? Please keep all that under your hat.

Answer (score 3):

It's just a glitch. The most reliable public live flight tracking site is Flightradar24.com (but even it has bugs), and it shows that CX806 has flown in more or less a straight line and will be arriving early.