# Strange flight path

Tags: flight-path

I am tracking my husbands plane from Tokyo to Chicago and saw a strange flight path. What would be some reasons for this?

[image: screenshot of flight path]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a bug in a flight visualization software.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do aircraft on Flight Radar 24 jump around randomly sometimes?](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/2269/why-do-aircraft-on-flight-radar-24-jump-around-randomly-sometimes)

Comment: Closing this as OT seems harsh. The possible dupe that [fooot listed](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/36579/strange-flight-path#comment94896_36579) is exactly the same question. I guess it's a minor semantic detail whether it's closed as dupe or OT, but I'd have voted dupe.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that is the actual flight path. Probably a software bug or faulty hardware.

Comment: The flight took off 1 hour late and is now running 5 hours behind