# Detecting plane or helicopter landing using ADS-B messages only

Tags: ads-b

Let's suppose I only have an ADS-B receiver.

I want to detect aircrafts landing at the receiver's location, and estimate the time they will take to land.

What would be the most reliable way to perform that estimation?

I can use the ground speed and baro rate if they are available, but I've seen that the baro/geom rate is often not available in the ADS-B messages.

Estimating the horizontal/vertical velocities from positions is not reliable (see [Why does ADS-B broadcast velocity?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/45434/why-does-ads-b-broadcast-velocity)).

What piece of information can I reasonably assemble from ADS-B data only?

Comment: What is the time accuracy you need to achieve? Are the aircraft landing at an airport?

Comment: @DeltaLima I should try to detect aircrafts trying to land at a location 5-10 minutes before they land. No real need for time accuracy. Not necessarily at an airport.

Comment: So you have a location, that isn't necessarily a runway, and you want to know 5-10 minutes beforehand that an aircraft is going to land there, yes? Since "mind reading" is beyond the scope of ADS-B (and any other known technology), what data to you believe *could* tell you that far in advance that an aircraft will be landing there, as opposed to just flying past?  With good position/velocity data, you could note that an aircraft is on course to fly near your position, but until they commit to landing there - well within 5 minutes of actual landing, in many cases - "near" is all you can know.

Comment: "*Estimating the horizontal/vertical velocities from positions is not reliable*" actually in your case the mean velocity from position is more useful than the Doppler instantaneous velocity from the GPS. Build a simple [Kalman filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter) to predict the landing time or use a [one from a library](https://filterpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). [More](https://machinelearningspace.com/object-tracking-python/).

Comment: @mins interesting suggestion to use the Kalman filter. My purpose is for turning on landing lights, so, for answering Ralph J considerations, it's better to turn on lights one once more rather than once less.