# Ground Speed On Approach

Tags: approach, stall, regional-jet

I'm not a pilot, just a bit of frequent flyer and moderate aviation enthusiast. I sometimes get on Flightaware and check on the flights I frequent and see the path that was taken and flight time. I noticed today on the track log that a ORD-GSO flight airspeed dropped below 100mph while lining up for the approach. I had never seen this before and was curious to how often this happens? Isn't this dangerously slow even for the short time?

https://flightaware.com/live/flight/ENY3619/history/20190517/1655Z/KORD/KGSO

Thanks!

Comment: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/2269/why-do-aircraft-on-flight-radar-24-jump-around-randomly-sometimes

Comment: If you look at the FlightAware track during the time the speed drops, this happens just as the aircraft makes a sharp turn. Given that the data comes from FlightAware's multilateration, this strikes me as a data error rather than the actual speed of the aircraft.

Comment: Welcome to aviation. SE! [This question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/5121/62) might be helpful. A key point is that speed over the ground and speed through the air are two different things, and only airspeed is important to keep flying safely. There are also issues with how FlightAware displays information but that's a separate topic.